# Kestrel seems to start but doesn't work when run as a different user

Tags: .net-core, privileges, kestrel

I have a small .net core WebAPI service running on kestrel. This is deployed automatically on multiple machines using TFS deployments. After deployment the automation tool runs this kestrel server on each deployed machine.
I can verify that:

- the application starts on each machine (dotnet process is present in Task Manager)
- the application listens on the correct port (because trying to run it manually on that port throws the error that port is in use)

BUT:

- for the automatically started application I cannot access the webapi service in browser (http://localhost:8081) -- says 404
- if I close the dotnet process started automatically and run it manually it works ok (WebApi accessible in browser)

Why doesn't it work correctly when started automatically? The only difference between processes seems to be the user under they are executed.
How could I troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Are there any differences between the commands which are run when the app is started automatically and manually?

Comment: Nope, absolutely identical